# Is there a way I can override the built-in operator for bytea in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, operator-overloading, pgadmin-4

I've created operators for overriding the default behavior for built-in (bytea,bytea) operators.
Is this even allowed? I need this to override the comparison of custom encoded binary data in the database.

```
CREATE OPERATOR = (
    LEFTARG = bytea,
    RIGHTARG = bytea,
    COMMUTATOR = =,
    NEGATOR = !=,
    PROCEDURE = fn_enc_eq,
    HASHES, MERGES
    );

CREATE OPERATOR != (
    LEFTARG = bytea,
    RIGHTARG = bytea,
    COMMUTATOR = =,
    NEGATOR = !=,
    PROCEDURE = fn_enc_neq,
    HASHES, MERGES
    );

CREATE OPERATOR >= (
    LEFTARG = bytea,
    RIGHTARG = bytea,
    PROCEDURE = fn_enc_gte,
    HASHES, MERGES
    );

CREATE OPERATOR > (
    LEFTARG = bytea,
    RIGHTARG = bytea,
    PROCEDURE = fn_enc_gt,
    HASHES, MERGES
    );

CREATE OPERATOR <= (
    LEFTARG = bytea,
    RIGHTARG = bytea,
    PROCEDURE = fn_enc_lte,
    HASHES, MERGES
    );

CREATE OPERATOR < (
    LEFTARG = bytea,
    RIGHTARG = bytea,
    PROCEDURE = fn_enc_lt,
    HASHES, MERGES
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly define these operators, but then you need to set the `search_path` so that the schema where you created the operators is included *before* `pg_catalog`, e.g. like this:

```
SET search_path = operatorschema, pg_catalog, appschema;
```

Note that that won't be effective everywhere you want. For example, if you plan to use a B-tree index on a `bytea` (strange idea), that would use the original operators. You'd have to define a custom operator class for that.

Rather than abusing `bytea`, it would be cleaner and better to define your own data type.